# JSON file not importing?

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm still pretty new to AngularJS, but this concerns importing from a JSON document.

I have a list of guitars which I've made all as objects in my JS file (And had it all working correctly), and I use ng-repeat to have all of them display. Now, I want to place those objects in a separate JSON file.

HTML template:

```
    <section id="guitarSections" ng-controller="GuitarCtrl">
        <div id="guitarDivs" data-ng-repeat="guitar in guitars">
            <img id="guitarImages" src="{{guitar.imageURL}}">

            <div id="text">
                <h2 class="information">{{guitar.title}}</h2>
                <p class="information">Instrument: {{guitar.instrument}}<p>
                <p class="information">Color: {{guitar.color}}</p>
                <p class="information">Price: {{guitar.price}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

    </section>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("GuitarCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    var url = "data.json";

    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        $scope.guitars = response.data;
    });
});
```

And a small sample of my JSON:

```
{
    "guitars":[ 
            {
                "title": "Yamaha Revstar 420",
                "brand": "Yamaha",
                "instrument": "Electric Guitar",
                "color": "Red",
                "price": "$499.99",
                "details": "Yes",
                "imageURL": "YamahaRS420.jpg"
            },

            {
                "title": "Yamaha Pacifica Series PAC012",
                "brand": "Yamaha",
                "instrument": "Electric Guitar",
                "color": "Blue",
                "price": "$",
                "details": "Yes",
                "imageURL": "YamahaPacificaSeriesPAC012.jpg"
            }
]}
```

When I run it on a Python Server (python -m SimpleHTTPServer), the page loads, but none of the content will get imported over and it only shows one guitar section.

ADDITIONAL NOTE: I also inspected the Network, and in the columns with the names of the documents, I happened to notice, in red, '%7B%7Bguitar.imageURL%7D%7D'. Upon examining this, a page pops up and gives me a 404, which says:

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Though I have checked and ensured that all of my documents' names are not misspelled and that each image can be imported.

Answer (score 0):

First, you expect your JSON to contain an array of guitars, but it actually contains an object with a single attribute named guitars.

Second, you should use ng-src rather than src for your IMG element, to avoid this request to a non-interpolated URL.